# In Beeminder, how to set your current level and your Goal?

Tags: beeminder

I have just started using Beeminder.com. I am having trouble understanding how to set a goal saying that "I have to read 47 pages of a book within today and I have read 0 until now." There seems to be only one number that I can enter and that number is set as my current level as well as what I started with as well as my goal. Here is a screenshot:

[image: Beeminder - Setting goals]

I have gone through reading the instructions, checking the settings numerous times but I still can't find anything.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just made a temporary test goal that I think does what you want:
  https://www.beeminder.com/d/test130

You'll want to put 0 as the starting value and 47 as the goal.

One problem may be that Beeminder doesn't like goals with a shorter horizon than one week. Everything is kind of built around the "akrasia horizon" -- you can change anything about your goal, including making it end altogether, starting a week in the future.

More generally, Beeminder is best for making steady, gradual progress toward a long-term goal. If it's more of a binary thing -- "I need to force myself to do XYZ tomorrow" -- then StickK might be the better choice.

(Thanks so much for asking this, btw. I'm a founder of Beeminder.)